# Cloning a frame/tab with swing components/buttons inside

Tags: java, swing

OK a complete revision:

I have a JFrame with a tab that has buttons/textfields etc. inside.Buttons have events that does simple things like reading from an SQL server and filling the textfields from the received query.Pretty simple eh? And now ,I need to add more tabs to this Frame and have to have multiple tabs.In each tab I "must" have the same components/events. So what I am asking is this,how can I clone all the components/events/keylisteners etc. (whatever i have inside that tab) to another tab? I could always add the same components with different names from the code,but I need to find a way to clone the whole tab..

Comment: Stop with the 'what I want to do' for the moment and tell us 'what feature I want to offer'.  It seems to me it needs a factory for making the 2 UIs, but the devil is in the details.

Comment: Well, actually all I need is the fundamentals of it.The app is not much of a complex thing,a simple program that writes/reads from an SQL server.It has buttons and textfields inside a tab.All i need to do is to clone the contents of the first tab to the second tab...

Comment: I am still not clear on the feature 'Show multiple clients at once!, 'Whiter, brighter, more sudsy.',  'Offers muli-lingual support' are features.  That collection of words (as I understand them) does not add up to one.

Comment: Hahah you gave me a good laugh here mate,cheers :)

Comment: All of the above and on top of it the format... it hurts my eyes :) I cannot read it mate and I will hold my down vote for the time being as I have a feeling that it just might be an interesting question or you can turn it into such. Please work on the text including all of the @AndrewThompson 's suggestions.

Comment: OK - seen the edit.  There is nothing in either the edit or your (vague) replies to my comments that indicates much besides what I first suggested 'it needs a factory'.

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep the components you already have without duplicating them, and figure out a way to store all the data to be displayed in some kind of model. You could create only some buttons to simulate the tabs, and when clicking on one you display the data associated with it.